# Insert multiples dates at start of every group in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, append

I have a dataframe with millions of groups.  I am trying to, for each group, add 3 months of dates (month end dates) at the top of every group. So if the first observation of a group is December 2019, I want to fill 3 rows prior to that observation with dates from September 2019 to November 2019.  I also want to fill the group column with the relevant group ID and the other columns can remain as null values.

Would like to avoid looping if possible as this is a very large dataset

This is my before DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

before = pd.DataFrame({'Group':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
    'Date':['31/10/2018','30/11/2018','31/12/2018','31/01/2019','28/02/2019','30/03/2001','30/04/2001','31/05/2001','30/06/2001','31/07/2001'],
    'value':[1.1,1.7,1.9,2.3,1.5,2.8,2,2,2,2]})
```

This is my after DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

after = pd.DataFrame({'Group':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
'Date':['31/07/2018','31/08/2018','30/09/2018','31/10/2018','30/11/2018','31/12/2018','31/01/2019','28/02/2019','31/12/2000','31/01/2001','28/02/2001','30/03/2001','30/04/2001','31/05/2001','30/06/2001','31/07/2001'],
'value':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1.1,1.7,1.9,2.3,1.5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2.8,2,2,2,2]})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because processing each group separately if many groups solution cannot be very fast - idea is get first rows of `Group` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), shift months by [`offsets.MonthOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset.html), join together and add all missing datets between:

```
before['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(before['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = before.drop_duplicates('Group')

#first and last shifted months - by 1 and by 3 months
df11 = df1[['Group','Date']].assign(Date = lambda x: x['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthOffset(3))
df12 = df1[['Group','Date']].assign(Date = lambda x: x['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthOffset(1))

df = (pd.concat([df11, df12], sort=False, ignore_index=True)
       .set_index('Date')
       .groupby('Group')
       .resample('m')
       .size()
       .reset_index(name='value')
       .assign(value = np.nan))
print (df)
   Group       Date  value
0      1 2018-07-31    NaN
1      1 2018-08-31    NaN
2      1 2018-09-30    NaN
3      2 2000-12-31    NaN
4      2 2001-01-31    NaN
5      2 2001-02-28    NaN
```

Last add to original and sorting:

```
df = pd.concat([before, df], ignore_index=True).sort_values(['Group','Date'])
```

---

```
print (df)
    Group       Date  value
10      1 2018-07-31    NaN
11      1 2018-08-31    NaN
12      1 2018-09-30    NaN
0       1 2018-10-31    1.1
1       1 2018-11-30    1.7
2       1 2018-12-31    1.9
3       1 2019-01-31    2.3
4       1 2019-02-28    1.5
13      2 2000-12-31    NaN
14      2 2001-01-31    NaN
15      2 2001-02-28    NaN
5       2 2001-03-30    2.8
6       2 2001-04-30    2.0
7       2 2001-05-31    2.0
8       2 2001-06-30    2.0
9       2 2001-07-31    2.0
```

If new months is only few you can omit `groupby` part:

```
before['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(before['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = before.drop_duplicates('Group')

df11 = df1[['Group','Date']].assign(Date = lambda x: x['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthOffset(3))
df12 = df1[['Group','Date']].assign(Date = lambda x: x['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthOffset(2))
df13 = df1[['Group','Date']].assign(Date = lambda x: x['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthOffset(1))

df = (pd.concat([df11, df12, df13, before], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
        .sort_values(['Group','Date']))

print (df)
    Group       Date  value
0       1 2018-07-31    NaN
2       1 2018-08-31    NaN
4       1 2018-09-30    NaN
6       1 2018-10-31    1.1
7       1 2018-11-30    1.7
8       1 2018-12-31    1.9
9       1 2019-01-31    2.3
10      1 2019-02-28    1.5
1       2 2000-12-30    NaN
3       2 2001-01-30    NaN
5       2 2001-02-28    NaN
11      2 2001-03-30    2.8
12      2 2001-04-30    2.0
13      2 2001-05-31    2.0
14      2 2001-06-30    2.0
15      2 2001-07-31    2.0
```